# btrfs - Unknown filesystem?

Tags: 11.04, btrfs

Today when I went ahead with Natty installation I had selected `btrfs` for `root` filesystem. To my utter surprise I was presented with the screen

> Unknown filesystem
>   grub rescue >

None of the options I tried like `Y`, `yes` did not work. Later I again installed Natty with `ext4` filesystem.

Why do such errors appear?

Comment: I need no more answers for the question as I have reinstalled Natty in an ext4 partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`btrfs` is considered experimental and unless you're very adventurous, you should avoid using it. There is neither a fsck tool available in case the `btrfs` filesystem becomes corrupt (after a power failure for example).

An excerpt from the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/ReleaseNotes/#btrfs):

> The btrfs filesystem is considered experimental in this release. It can generally be installed and used, but with a number of problems. You should only use it if you are comfortable with dealing with problems and helping us resolve them.

- As the btrfs wiki notes: "Note that Btrfs does not yet have a fsck tool that can fix errors. While Btrfs is stable on a stable machine, it is currently possible to corrupt a filesystem irrecoverably if your machine crashes or loses power on disks that don't handle flush requests correctly. This will be fixed when the fsck tool is ready."
- GRUB cannot detect a btrfs installation within an encrypted disk, and fails to set up the correct kernel parameters. (757631)

GRUB can actually boot from btrfs filesystems ([instructions](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Getting_started#Ubuntu_Linux_11.04_.28Natty_Narwhal.29_Btrfs_Full_Disk_Encryption)), but note that Ubuntu still consider btrfs as experimental.

Comment: I knew it was experimental, but remember seeing people boasting of using `btrfs` and getting fast boot times. How could they boot into Ubuntu when I got **unknown filesystem**.

Comment: @Chethan S.: Install the bootloader to either the MBR of the disk or create a new `/boot` partition, formatted ext2. See the [Ubuntu Wiki article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs#Fresh%20Install%20on%2011.04-beta1%20Natty).

Comment: GRUB *can* boot from btrfs in 11.04.  There are problems, certainly, but it is inaccurate to say "GRUB cannot boot from that filesystem".

Comment: I've successfully booted from btrfs /, both single disc and a 4-disc btrfs multidevice system.  I didn't do anything special to make that happen :).  It was *slow as molasses*, but it worked.

Comment: @Colin: I've made the answer more correct now.

Answer (score 1):

btrfs is the future of filesystems  check: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page
 But it is just a child and not yet ready completely. btrfs is very fast, but I will not recommend it for a person who wants a stable system. 
If you want to see some technical aspects of btrfs you can visit
http://lwn.net/Articles/342892/

Answer (score 1):

First, try [reinstalling GRUB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#METHOD%203%20-%20CHROOT).  Is there any output from `grub-install` when you do that?  If so, post it here.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that your problem was a version of grub that did not, or did not correctly, support btrfs.  There are two solutions.  Either give your system a separate, ext2/3 boot partition, or use the latest version of grub that supports btrfs in a much cleaner manner.